# how to sum based on three different condition in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, sum

The following is my data.

```
gcode code year   P  Q
1      101  2000  1  3
1      101  2001  2  4
1      102  2000  1  1
1      102  2001  4  5
1      102  2002  2  6
1      102  2003  6  5
1      103  1999  6  1
1      103  2000  4  2
1      103  2001  2  1
2      104  2000  1  3
2      104  2001  2  4
2      105  2001  4  5
2      105  2002  2  6
2      105  2003  6  5
2      105  2004  6  1
2      106  2000  4  2
2      106  2001  2  1
```

`gcode` 1 has 3 different codes 101, 102 and 103. They all have the same year (2000 and 2001). I want to sum up `P` and `Q` for these years. Otherwise, I want to delete the irrelevant data. I want to do the same for `gcode` 2 as well.

How can I get the result like this?

```
gcode  year   P       Q
1      2000   1+1+4   3+1+2
1      2001   2+4+2   4+5+1
2      2001   2+4+2   4+5+1
```

Comment: please delete the first row "1 2000 5 5",gcode=1 don't have the data in 2000,because code=102 don't have data in 2000

Comment: Yes,thank you very much! Do you know how to make it quickly in R?

Comment: Please edit your question to what you would accurately expect. It's confusing otherwise.

Comment: sorry, it's my first time to ask a question. I make a stupid mistake, sorry about that. Now, i guess it is clear. For gcode=1,code=101,102,103 all have data in 2001;gcode =2, is also the same

Comment: sorry for all of you guys, i am totally new here. Now i make the last change to my input and output. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with the following solution. First, I counted how many times each year appear for each `gcode`. I also counted how many unique codes exist for each `gcode`. Then, join the two results using `left_join()`. Then, I identified rows that have same values in `n_year` and `n_code`. Then, I joined the original data frame, which is called `mydf`. Then, I defined groups by `gcode` and `year`, and summed up `P` and `Q` for each group.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(count(mydf, gcode, year, name = "n_year"),
          group_by(mydf, gcode) %>% summarize(n_code = n_distinct(code))) %>% 
filter(n_year == n_code) %>% 
left_join(mydf, by = c("gcode", "year")) %>% 
group_by(gcode, year) %>% 
summarize_at(vars(P:Q),
             .funs = list(~sum(.)))

#  gcode  year     P     Q
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1  2000     6     6
#2     1  2001     8    10
#3     2  2001     8    10
```

**Another idea**

I was reviewing this question later and came up with the following idea, which is much simpler. First, I defined groups by `gcode` and `year`. For each group, I counted how many data points existed using `add_count()`. Then, I defined groups again with `gcode` only. For each gcode group, I wanted to get rows that meet `n == n_distinct(code)`. `n` is a column created by `add_count()`. If a number in `n` and a number returned by `n_distinct()` matches, that means that a year in that row exists among all `code`. Finally, I defined groups by `gcode` and `year` again and summed up values in `P` and `Q`.

```
group_by(mydf, gcode, year) %>% 
add_count() %>% 
group_by(gcode) %>% 
filter(n == n_distinct(code)) %>%
group_by(gcode, year) %>% 
summarize_at(vars(P:Q),
             .funs = list(~sum(.)))

# This is the same code in data.table.
setDT(mydf)[, check := .N, by = .(gcode, year)][,
            .SD[check == uniqueN(code)], by = gcode][,
            lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = P:Q, by = .(gcode, year)][]
```

Comment: yes, i have the same logic with you. But i just can not have the output. Thank you very much!

Comment: One more question,If i want to extract the output data in excel, for your method,how could i make it ?

Comment: You mean you want to save the result as an excel file?

Comment: Pleasure to help you. :)

Comment: a<-count(data1, gcode, year, name = "n_year")
b<-summarize(group_by(data1, gcode),n_code = n_distinct(code))
c<-left_join(a,b) 
d<-filter(c,n_year==n_code)
e<-summarize_at(group_by(data1,gcode, year),vars(P:Q),.funs = list(~sum(.)))
g<-left_join(d,e)

Comment: data1 is my data, inspired by your answer,now i give my own answer which is easy to understand. Could you tell me how to post my answer? Because it always tells me that“Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.”

Comment: @XUNZHANG What you suggested in your comment is basically what I wrote. When you answer your own question, you want to provide a different answer. If I comment your code, it is surely easy to understand, but you are creating many objects, which means you are using more memories. All answers here avoid doing it, as you see. Ronak and I used dplyr package. %>% is passing an output to another function. This is handy since we do not have to create new objects every single time. In short, my suggestion is to avoid your own code. You can surely keep that in your own computer.

Comment: Oh,sorry about that. I am totally new here and don't know the rules. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @XUNZHANG No worries. I was like you a couple of years ago. Have a look of how people behave for some time.

Comment: @XUNZHANG Hi again. It has been like two week since you asked this question. I had a chance to review this post again and came up with a better idea. If you have time, have a look.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, jazzurro. I solve the problem now, but I have another paoblem,  do you know how to use the Maximium Likelihood Estimation (MLE) method to estimate the Vasicek model's parameter? I search a lot, but don't find the answer. In R, I want to use the package SMFI5, but one of my output is so large, I don't know why.I ask the question in stackexchang, if you know the answer,please let me know.You can search the question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444021/why-one-of-my-estimated-paramatersigmaof-vasicek-model-is-so-large-in-r

Comment: @XUNZHANG I am afraid I have no clue about that package. I am sure someone out there can give you a hand!

Answer (score 4):

We can `split` the data based on `gcode` subset the data based on common `year` which is present in all the `code` and `aggregate` the data by `gcode` and `year`.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$gcode), function(x) {
      aggregate(cbind(P, Q)~gcode+year, 
               subset(x, year %in% Reduce(intersect, split(x$year, x$code))), sum)
}))

#    gcode year P  Q
#1.1     1 2000 6  6
#1.2     1 2001 8 10
#2       2 2001 8 10
```

---

Using `dplyr` with similar logic we can do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_split(gcode) %>%
  purrr::map_df(. %>% 
                 group_by(year) %>% 
                 filter(n_distinct(code) == n_distinct(.$code)) %>% 
                 group_by(gcode, year) %>%
                 summarise_at(vars(P:Q), sum))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(gcode = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), code = c(101L, 101L, 102L, 102L, 
102L, 102L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 104L, 104L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 
106L, 106L), year = c(2000L, 2001L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 
2000L, 2001L), P = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 2L), Q = c(3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

Comment: Yeah!I get the answer now. Thanks again!

Comment: One more question,If i want to extract the output data in excel, for these two methods,how could i make it ?

Comment: @XUNZHANG you can store the output of the above in a variable `new_file <- do.call(rbind......rest of the code` and the use `write.csv(new_file, 'filename.csv', row.names = FALSE)` as open it in excel.

Comment: I got it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

An option using `data.table` package:

```
years <- DT[, {
    m <- min(year)
    ty <- tabulate(year-m)
    .(year=which(ty==uniqueN(code)) + m)
}, gcode]

DT[years, on=.(gcode, year),
    by=.EACHI, .(P=sum(P), Q=sum(Q))]
```

output:

```
   gcode year P  Q
1:     1 2000 6  6
2:     1 2001 8 10
3:     2 2001 8 10
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("gcode code year   P  Q
1      101  2000  1  3
1      101  2001  2  4
1      102  2000  1  1
1      102  2001  4  5
1      102  2002  2  6
1      102  2003  6  5
1      103  1999  6  1
1      103  2000  4  2
1      103  2001  2  1
2      104  2000  1  3
2      104  2001  2  4
2      105  2001  4  5
2      105  2002  2  6
2      105  2003  6  5
2      105  2004  6  1
2      106  2000  4  2
2      106  2001  2  1")
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. i will try your answer.